# matplotlib discrepancy with iPython notebook and python file

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have a strange problem with matplotlib that I can not seem to figure out. When using the ipython notebook with the pylab flag, `ipython notebook --pylab inline` I have a line of code that looks like this that is used to generate a colorbar with matplotlib:

```
im = ax.imshow(df, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

The code works correctly and I get a nice colorbar. When I run this code as a python file I get an error, `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`. I understand that the `ipython notebook --pylab inline` automatically imports a bunch of stuff into the notebook, but I cannot figure out what I need to import to fix the problem. `print type(ax)` gives:

```
<class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>
```

Can anyone point out why my code works in ipython but not a plain python file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
Per this entry:
[How to abbreviate xtick labels years to 2 digits in a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308512/how-to-abbreviate-xtick-labels-years-to-2-digits-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

try defining 'ax' by adding (before the line causing the error):

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you've done, because `aX` isn't defined by default as part of pylab.

Normally, `ax` refers to an axis object. There are a few ways you can get one:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.gca()            # gca = get current axis
matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(2,1,1)   # For creating multiple plots in one figure
fig.get_axes()[x]                  # Where fig is a Figure object
```